# Database design relationship for movie

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, bigdata

I created a table of movie in MySQL that has one million movies for example with id and name column. I also create user table with id, name columns and a comment table that has movie_id and user_id and comment columns to save all user comments.

My question is if I have 1 million movies and if each movie has 1000 comments (lets say we have 1000 active users), then the comment table should have 1,000,000,000  rows and it is so slow to use a query to find all comment on one specific movie.

Any of you friends can help me with better solution or way to do this?

here are the queries that I use to create tables of my project:

movie_tb:

```
create table movie_tb (id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,movie_name   varchar(30) not null);
```

user_table:

```
create table user_tb (id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,user_name   varchar(30) not null);
```

comment_tb:

```
create table comment_tb(id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,movie_id   bigint not null,user_id bigint not null,comment varchar(250));
```

movie_table looks like this:

```
+---------+--------------+  
|  id     |  movie_name  |  
+---------+--------------+  
|  1      |  Joker       |  
+---------+--------------+  
+---------+--------------+  
|  2      |  Avatar      |  
+---------+--------------+  
+---------+--------------+  
|  3      | Harry potter |  
+---------+--------------+
```

movie_tb has 100,000 row.

there is user_tb:

```
+---------+--------------+  
|id       |   name       |  
+---------+--------------+  
+---------+--------------+  
|  1      | jack         |  
+---------+--------------+  
+---------+--------------+  
|    2    |     joy      |  
+---------+--------------+
```

user_tb has 10,000 row.

here is comment_tb:

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  id     | movie_id     | user_id       | comment       |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  1      | 1            | 2             | comment1      |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  2      | 1            | 3             | comment2      |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  3      | 1            | 5             | comment3      |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  4      | 1            | 1024          | comment4      |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  5      | 1475         | 505           | comment       |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  6      | 1475         | 56            | comment       |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  7      | 2            | 2             | comment       |  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  8      | 1            | 8761          | comment5      |   
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|  ...    | ...          |  ...          |   ...         |   
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+  
|31000000 | 1            | 36            | comment6      | 
+---------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

here is a small of rows inside comment_tb: there are 6 comments on joker(movei_id=1
refer to movie id in movie_tb and comment are from user_id 2,3,5,1024,8761,36 that refer to id of users in user_tb.

this table(commnet_tb) have 31 million rows;
I use this query:

```
select comment from comment_tb where movie_id= 1;
```

to get all comments on movie_id 1 which is joker, but it get a result after 8 or some times 30 seconds.

Comment: That's what `INDEXes` are for!

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for every table involved for us to see the scope of your volume of data and the columns involved in each table.  Never use SELECT * for any query if you are needing high performance on any table, name the columns needed to answer your queries.

Comment: Your typing a long comment does not help when we ask for specific information. Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for every table involved for us to see the scope of your volume of data and the columns involved in each table. Never use SELECT * for any query if you are needing high performance on any table, name the columns needed to answer your queries. Also post the TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT comment FROM my_table WHERE move_id = 109;  With this information we can better assist you.

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Also re line breaks. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Please delete your comments when they are no longer needed. Please act on everything in the comments, not just some parts.

Comment: Thank you wilsom Hauck i use index on movie_id and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a billion of comments then a solution with a relational database requires a billion of rows for the comments table.

On the other hand this does not slow down queries if you design correctly the database: just add an index on the user_id and movie_id columns of the comments table, and the query that finds all the comments for a certain film, or all the comments of a certain user, will be answered very efficiently, without “scanning” all the table.

Comment: Tanks.but i create a comment_movie table with movie_id , user_id and comment columns . I fill table with random data up to 31million rows.then add 30 row with same movie_id and difrent user_id and comment.then run a query like this : find comment from comment_movie where movie_id =1765498; then it take 8 or more longer to get the resault.some time it take 30 seconds.

Comment: Did you add indexes?

Comment: You mean like an id(primary key auto_increment) ? Yes.but i think there is no reason use id in query or i missing some thing. I just need movie id to find all comments on one movie. Rows are like this:( id,movie_id,user_id,comment) and data for row one like (1,109,6543,comment1) and row2 (2,109,7654,comment2) and so on.id doesn't help i thing because query need movie_id to filter comments on specific movie. Indexes are unique on each row.but comment on one movie need several row that have same movie_ids. I realy need this to work.can you give me more detail?please

Comment: I need movie_id to filter query like :select * from mytb where movie_id=109.

Comment: You need an index on movie_id in the comments table. see a guide for instance [here](https://use-the-index-luke.com).

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL is the only choice you have to store the comments then based on your use case you can also look at partitioning the data for user comments.